# Find elements in one column (reg. exp.) then replace in another column

Tags: r, substitution

I seem to be stuck behind some really simple problem. I just cannot figure it out nor can I find an answer here. I tried  searching stackoverflow for almost an hour.

I want to find rows based on one column (direction "backward") and then multiply those rows in another column (amount) with -1 or any number for that matter.

1. amount  direction
2. 1 forward
3. 2 forward
4. 3 forward
5. 4 forward
6. 1 backward
7. 2 backward
8. 3 backward

So that I would get

1. amount direction
2. 1 forward
3. 2 forward
4. 3 forward
5. 4 forward
6. -1 backward
7. -2 backward
8. -3 backward

I know how to find the rows: df[grep("backward",df$direction),]
or how to multiply in general- df[,1]=df[,1]*(-1)
but I cannot put it together. I can pull out the ones I need and then multiply and then rbind or cbidn but if I have a really big df with many columns and rows I dont want to start pasting it all together again I just want to change something in one column based on another column. 
I managed something like this but it does not want to multiply :
df$amount[df$direction %in% c("backward")] <- (*(-1))
df$amount[grep("backward",df$direction)]<-(*(-1))
always get the same error: 
Error: unexpected '*' in "df$amount[grep("backward",df$direction)]<-*"

And I'm really sorry if this question exists already somewhere. I did find lots of similar questions but they did not help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: The error you get seems like a syntactic error. Why do you use both `df$direction %in% "backward"` and `grepl("backward", df$direction)`? You don't need to calculate the "backward" rows more than once; saving a variable "i" after `grep` or `"%in%"` and using `df$amount[i] = df$amount[i] * (-1)` should get what you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! 
I didnt use them both at the same time I just tried using either or, but neither worked :D for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

so as alexis said the answer is:

df$amount [grep ("backward", df$direction)] <-  df$amount [grep ("backward", df$direction)]* (-1)

OR

df$amount [df$direction %in% c("backward")] <- df$amount [df$direction %in% c("backward")]* (-1)